# Frames + Internet Explorer oddities

Tags: javascript, html, css, caching, frames

I'm running into some very odd beheaviour regarding frames and internet explorer.

The situation is like this:

- I have my web application on www.webapp.com
- I have a client that wants to have a login box to my www.webapp.com on his website: www.vendor.com
- The vendor his website is setup by his webdesigner at www.vendor.com. It consists of 2 frames:

  - First frame spans 100% height and width and it's location is at www.webdedesigner.com/clients/vendor
  - Second frame spans 0,0 and doesn't point to anything

The login box on the remote site points to my web application. And posts login+username etc.
The reason the client's website is setup with the frames is so that the browser's URL location bar always is kept at www.vendor.com. (Ugh, don't even get me started).

The problem is when I login  from www.vendor.com to my web app, and my web app is loaded in the frame all of my CSS and Javascript is not loaded.

This only occurs in IE7/8, I've tested it in Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari and each one of them does load my CSS and JS files at it should.

This is how my header looks like:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="nl" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"> 
  <head> 
    <title>My Webapp</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" /> 
    <link rel="icon" href="/img/favicon.ico" /> 
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon.ico" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/css.php?css=public" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/js.php?js=public"></script> 
  </head> 
  <body>
```

I'm suspecting IE doesn't handle the relatie URL's of the CSS/JS correctly...

There's an even more odd thing! If i clear my IE browsing cache and I first login to www.webapp.com via that domain, and than logout and login via www.vendor.com in IE, the CSS/JS does load! What the...? My whole webapp resides on HTTPS so it shouldn't be caching any resources...

I'm flabergasted so I resort to posting here.. anyone know what's up?

**Edit**

Okay, after I installed a proper debugging tool for Internet Explorer (instead of the default one), I was able to inspect the HTTP headers beeing sent. So I compared IE and Firefox and these results showed up:

**IE Request Login post to my webapp**

```
(Request-Line):POST /?portal&returnurl=www.vendor.com HTTP/1.1
Accept:application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Host:www.webapp.nl
Content-Length:40
Connection:Keep-Alive
Cache-Control:no-cache
```

**IE Response**

```
(Status-Line):HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date:Wed, 14 Jul 2010 10:35:34 GMT
Server:Apache
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.1.6
**Set-Cookie:PHPSESSID=uiluornfipr2dk294iro09tgg6; path=/**
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma:no-cache
Set-Cookie:lang=0
Set-Cookie:lang=0
Connection:close
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

**IE CSS Request:**

```
(Request-Line):GET /css/css.php?css=portal HTTP/1.1
Accept:*/*
Host:www.webapp.nl
Connection:Keep-Alive
```

**IE CSS Response**

```
(Status-Line):HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date:Wed, 14 Jul 2010 10:35:35 GMT
Server:Apache
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.1.6
**Set-Cookie:PHPSESSID=pe2cio1vhu0shq2i497bjh5oa4; path=/**
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma:no-cache
Content-Length:0
Connection:close
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

**Firefox Request Login post to my webapp**

```
Host    www.webapp.nl
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language nl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Connection  keep-alive
```

**FF Response**

```
Date    Wed, 14 Jul 2010 10:38:57 GMT
Server  Apache
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.1.6
**Set-Cookie    PHPSESSID=re10rmqq7u723ht3719o9q5el3; path=/ lang=0 lang=0**
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma  no-cache
Connection  close
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

**FF CSS Request**

```
Host    www.webapp.nl
Accept  text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Language nl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Connection  keep-alive
**Cookie    PHPSESSID=re10rmqq7u723ht3719o9q5el3; lang=0**
```

**FF CSS Response**

```
Date    Wed, 14 Jul 2010 10:38:57 GMT
Server  Apache
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.1.6
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma  no-cache
Connection  close
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Content-Type    text/css; charset=utf-8
```

(Removed some for brevity)

The difference is obvious. IE doesn't sent the cookie along with the CSS request, even though it did receive a set-cookie from the login response. Firefox does sent the cookie along with the CSS request.
And my webapp doesn't return CSS/Script unless a valid cookie was set.

Soo, any frame/cookie guru knows why IE doesn't send along the cookies it received in the first response in further resource requests for a page it's loading?

> Blockquote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default IE blocks cookies from third party sites, you should note in the status bar that the privacy eye becomes active and it states that it has blocked the cookies at your site.

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be the case, after i login the privacy eye does appear. 
---
I don't understand it though. The setting of cookie should be done fore the www.webapp.com domain, regardless of wether the browser's location bar is directly displaying the www.webapp.com or it's displaying www.webapp.com via an frameset. 
---
I understand i'm not allowed to set the cookie for the www.vendor.com domain, but why would IE think i'd want to do that? (And all other browsers don't, they understand i set the cookie for www.webapp.com domain)?

Comment: IE knows that you want to set the cookies for your webapp.com domain, but that page is a frame inside vendor.com. As those domains are different, the default configuration of IE is to block the requests by webapp.com domain to set any cookie. IIRC you can get around this using some P3P header when you set the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't ?js=public getting cut off ?